# How to run github nodejs Clone

Tags: php, node.js, github

I download one project from github

[Github Code](https://github.com/deepam1982/yantram.git)

How to run this project from my Linux . I already installed Node js npm and whatever it needed. But don't know how to run tihs

Answer (score 0):

You're super lost. Here's a list of resources to get you started.

google: "git and github basics tutorial" -> [result](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

google: "how to run a node project" -> [result](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html)

What I'm trying to get across is that by asking google the right questions, you can get started. It sounds like you don't know what you don't know, and that's okay too, that's why I provided what terms i searched for when getting you the resources you need. Hope these help.

Comment: @Janmabhumi please mark the answer as a solution and +1 if you find it helpful. :)

Comment: Less than 15 Reputaion

Comment: What? Less than 15 rep?

Comment: **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.** @Patrick motard

Comment: Ohh. Interesting. I didn't know that. Are you able to mark my answer as the solution?